How to Properly Inject Service Account Credentials in Google Cloud Build for Cloud Run Deployment?
I’m deploying a Laravel application to Google Cloud Run using Google Cloud Build. During the Docker build process, I need to access Google Secret Manager to inject secrets into the application code automatically. However, the build process fails with the following error:
Failed to load secrets: cURL error 28: Failed to connect to 169.***.***.** port 80 after 130458 ms: Couldn't connect to server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://169.***.***.**/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

As I understand it, the build process is trying to access the Google Cloud Instance Metadata Server at 169...** to retrieve a token for the default service account. However, the metadata server is not available in Cloud Build, as it doesn’t run on a virtual machine.
I’m not sure how to correctly inject these credentials into the Docker build process for this specific scenario.

What I’m Trying to Achieve:

Build a Docker image for the Laravel app using Cloud Build. ❌
Access secrets from Secret Manager during the build (e.g., database credentials, API keys). ✅
Inject the secrets into the Docker image automatically for use in
the application. ✅

Steps 2 and 3 work perfectly in local development (via gcloud auth application-default login) and Dockerized environments (by mounting a JSON file with Service Account credentials).
Build via Cloud Build fails due to application not being able to access secrets manager.

What I’ve Tried:

Created a Service Account with all necessary permissions for Secret Manager (roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor).
Stored the Service Account key JSON file securely.
Modified my cloudbuild.yaml to inject the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable during the build process.

However, the build process still fails, as Cloud Build cannot access the metadata server.

Current Workflow:
Here’s what I expect and currently envision as the workflow:


What I Need:

Guidance on the best way to inject Service Account credentials into the Cloud Build process.
Should I use a Service Account JSON key directly, or is there a way to configure the Cloud Build Service Account to access Secret Manager during the build?

Any help or insights on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

It is an anti-pattern to use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and/or to inject Service Account keys when the service is running on Google Cloud. A key aspect of Application Default Credentials is that the mechanism detects when code is running on a Google compute service and uses the identity (i.e. Service Account) associated with the process to acquire credentials. You should consider running your Cloud Build job using a user-defined Service Account with suitable role(s) to acquire|use secrets necessary for the build process.

The asset that's created by Cloud Build should not include hard-coded secrets. In the case where the asset uses a Google identity (e.g. Service Account), the Service Account should be associated with the process at runtime. Again, usually you will want to use ADC to acquire credentials and, as before, if the process is running on a Google Cloud compute service, these should be acquired from the identity associated with the process.

Indeed, that’s exactly what I expected when assigning a proper Service Account (SA) with the necessary roles to Cloud Build. My goal is to avoid any hard-coded credentials and ensure secrets are accessed only on-demand during the build process via the assigned SA.
However, I encountered issues where my application, running inside a Docker container, didn’t seem to inherit any linked SA permissions—effectively leaving it without the ability to access required resources. As for secrets needed during the build process, ADC is required to fetch other ones via the Secret Manager API.

It should be possible for Cloud Build to use a Service Account (SA) to authenticate with the Google Cloud PHP library specifically during the build process, right?

Yes, we appear to be saying the same thing. However, the evidence (that you have a problem) suggests you're not applying it. You will have minimally a user-defined Cloud Build service accounts that, besides Cloud Build permissions will need Secret Manager permissions for build time secrets. The asset will then be built. (is it?). Then you will need a user-defined Cloud Run service account that, besides Cloud Run permissions will need Secret Manager permissions for runtime permissions. That will work.

Cloud Build jobs run as the default Compute Engine Service Account but you should use a user-defined Service Account. When you run a PHP step in a Cloud Build job. If the PHP code uses a Google SDK (and therefore uses ADC), then it will be run as this Service Account identity too.

Yep, I do have a Service Account with the necessary configuration. During the Cloud Build process, the Docker container attempts to access the Secret Manager API to fetch secrets and map them as environment variables.
The issue arises because the codebase within the container doesn’t seem to have sufficient permissions. It times out when trying to access the secrets metadata server, causing the build to fail. This happens because the method is invoked within the constructor of one of the service methods. Therefore, ADC isn't loaded. Let me try to update my cloudbuild.yaml configuration.

As expected, I’m encountering the following error:
Your default credentials were not found. To set up ADC, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc
This happens during the Docker build process, and it seems the application cannot locate the required credentials for ADC. The default Service Account has all the necessary permissions. Is there a recommended example of a cloudbuild.yaml file?

The issue was primarily related to how services were being injected, which caused the build process to sometimes fail before reaching the required entry point.
Additionally, the cloudbuild.yaml configuration was incomplete. Expecting the automatic injection of a Service Account (SA) to specific CI/CD steps is totally accurate.
Here’s an example of a complete cloudbuild.yaml that resolved the issue:
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
  dynamicSubstitutions: true

steps:
  # Step 1: Build the Docker image for the application
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    id: Build
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-f'
      - Dockerfile
      - '-t'
      - ${_IMAGE_NAME}
      - .

  # Step 2: Push the Docker image to Google Artifact Registry
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    id: Push
    args:
      - push
      - ${_IMAGE_NAME}

  # Step 3: Deploy the Docker image to Cloud Run with secrets management
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    id: Deploy
    args:
      - run
      - deploy
      - ${_SERVICE_NAME}
      - '--image'
      - ${_IMAGE_NAME}
      - '--platform=managed'
      - '--region'
      - ${_REGION}
      - '--allow-unauthenticated'
      - '--memory=1024Mi'
      - '--set-secrets=EXAMPLE_API_KEY=my-api-key:latest'

  # Step 4: Execute a Cloud Run Job for database migrations
  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
    id: Migrate
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        gcloud run jobs execute migrate-job \
          --region ${_REGION}

substitutions:
  _ARTIFACT_REGISTRY: 'example-europe-north1-registry'
  _SERVICE_NAME: 'example-service-name'
  _REGION: 'europe-north1'
  _IMAGE_NAME: '${_REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/${_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY}/${_SERVICE_NAME}:${SHORT_SHA}'

images:
 - ${_IMAGE_NAME}

Key Notes
Local Testing with Docker:

When running locally in a Dockerized environment, mount a service-account.json file in docker-compose.yml to authenticate.

Local Non-Docker Testing:

Use gcloud auth application-default login to ensure your local environment is authenticated with GCP.

Service Account Injection:

In this setup, the Service Account (SA) is injected automatically where needed, ensuring all steps can authenticate successfully, and not following an anti-pattern of using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as mentioned by @DazWilkin.

Secrets Management:

After deployment, the application can successfully access the Secrets Manager API to retrieve and map secrets.


This configuration resolved the issue, ensuring both the CI/CD pipeline and the deployed application worked seamlessly with the necessary Service Account permissions.
